# alert for unsaved changes in Vue Js

Tags: javascript, events, vue.js, alert, dom-events

I'm attempting to alert the client of unsaved changes in the `beforeRouteLeave (to, from, next)` route hook of one of my `Vue` components. I'm want to display the following prompt on either navigation or reload:

[image]
[image]

I'm attempting to use the `window.onbeforeunload` event, but isn't firing properly:

```
  beforeRouteLeave (to, from, next) {
    if (!this.changesSaved) {
            const answer = window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
                return 'Do you really want to leave? you have unsaved changes!';
            };
          if (answer) {
            return next()
          } else {
            return next(false)
          }
    }
    return next()
  }
```

What am i doing wrong here syntactically?

Answer (score 1):

Thats probably because windowunload is not used, since the window is never really unloaded?? Im not actually sure.  But judging by the way Vue works, I assume this is why.

So maybe just use confirm?

```
beforeRouteLeave (to, from, next) {
if (!this.changesSaved) {
        const answer = window.confirm = function(e) {
            return 'Do you really want to leave? you have unsaved changes!';
        };
      if (answer) {
        return next()
      } else {
        return next(false)
      }
}
return next()
}
```

Comment: this doesnt fire when the page is reloaded sadly :(

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you are using beforeRouterLeave hook in a child component of your route component. So you have to trigger that hook in your route component directly.

> Finally, you can directly define route navigation guards inside route components (**the ones passed to the router configuration**) with the following options...

Here is [the reference](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards)